# awk to strore string format in variable

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` when I `echo` `f` it is empty, but if I remove the `$f` I get the desired results, however the new formatting is not stored in the `$d` variable. Basically I am trying to convert the string in `$d` variable into a new formatted variable `$f`. Thank you :).

**file**

```
ID,1A
DATE,220102
```

**awk**

```
d=$(awk -F, '/Date/ {print $2}' file) | f=$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d')
```

**f**    --- desired ---

```
2022-01-02
```

Comment: What you show under the heading **awk** isn't awk, it's shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use it this way to return a value from awk and set a shell variable:

```bash
f=$(date -d "$(awk -F, '/DATE/ {print $2}' file)" +'%Y-%m-%d')

echo "$f"
2022-01-02
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="-"} $1=="DATE"{ print "20" substr($2,1,2), substr($2,3,2), substr($2,5,2) }' file
```

Output:

```
2022-01-02
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Using `awk`'s `match` function capability to use regex `^DATE,([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$` for getting required output. This creates 3 capturing groups and stores matched values into array named `arr` once this match is done then printing `20` and all 3 values of arrays separated by `-` as per required output.

```
awk -v OFS="-" '
match($0,/^DATE,([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/,arr){
  print "20" arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers provide a more efficient method of reformatting the date (and assuming OP has no need for `d` in follow-on code), I'm going to focus solely on a couple issues with OP's current code:

- in the `awk` script need to match for (all caps) `DATE` instead of `Date`
- current code attempts to pipe the output from `d=$(...)` to the `f=$(...)` portion of code; while this does 'work' in that `f` will be assigned `2022-01-02` the problem is that the assignment to `f` is performed in a subprocess and upon exiting the subprocess `f` is effectively 'unassigned'; what OP really needs is to separate the `d=$(...)` and `f=$(...)` commands from each other so that both assignments occur in the current shell, and this can be done by replacing the pipe with a semicolon.

If we make these two simple edits:

```
# old code:

d=$(awk -F, '/Date/ {print $2}' file) | f=$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d')
              ^^^^                   ^^^

# new code:

d=$(awk -F, '/DATE/ {print $2}' file) ; f=$(date -d "$d" +'%Y-%m-%d')
              ^^^^                   ^^^
```

OP's code will now generate the desired result:

```
$ echo "${f}"
2022-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

the string approaches :

> ```
> {n,g}awk -F'^[^,]*,' 'gsub("^....|..", "-&", $(_=!(NF*=NF==NR)))\
>              ($+_ = substr($+_,++_+_--))^_'  OFS=20
> ```

> ```
> mawk -F'^[^,]*,' '$(gsub("^....|..", "-&", 
>                   $!(NF*=NF==NR))*(_=!NF)) = substr($_,++_+_)' OFS=20
>
> mawk2 'gsub("^....|..", "-&", 
>        $!(NF*=NF==NR)) + sub(".",_)^_' FS='^.+,' OFS=20
> ```

the numeric approach :

> ```
> mawk -F',' 'NF==NR && ($!NF = sprintf("20%.*s-%.*s-%0*.f", _+=_^=_<_,
>                    __ = $NF, _++, substr(__,_), --_, __%(_+_*_*_)^_))'
> ```

```
2022-01-02
```